# Not able to access remote Vagrant VM via ssh anymore

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

I got into a big trouble when I changed the IP address of my remote **Vagrant VM** machine ***(Ubuntu 14.04 5 LTS)*** to a static IP address. 
I changed the default settings by going into /etc/network/interfaces folder. I rebooted the networking service and my VM after that.
I followed the regular procedure of logging in via Putty and then using "vagrant ssh" in order to connect to my machine.

**The Problem:**   Since I changed the IP address, I am able to login via Putty but when I type in vagrant ssh in order to get to VM command line, it displays the following error:
**ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer**

I want to go to /etc/network/interfaces in order to change the settings back to default (or as they were earlier) but I cannot do that until I am able to connect to the vagrant through ssh.
Any kind of help or guidance will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While using vagrant, you do not need to modify the /etc/network files, thats the magic trick of vagrant. You will setup everything in the [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) and vagrant will make all the update for you. Since you change the network files yourself, vagrant tries to ssh based on its Vagrantfile but this is not inline with your VM config.

You can make all [network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/) update on the Vagrantfile and setup a static IP from there.

Vagrant is using a NAT interface as the 1st network interface (read https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/vagrant-up-and/9781449336103/ch04.html for more) so if you have assigned something else on the 1st interface, this needs to be removed. Login with putty directly to the VM and make the update.